# Flink - How to align watermarks of two datastreams in a cogroup operation？

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Recently, I have developed a flink application. The logic is to make a cogroup operation with two datastreams that consume data from Kafka, the  traffic ratio is 10:1. Back pressure usually happens on the datastream with large amount at the runtime. Because of that, the distance of the two datastreams’ watermarks become larger and larger, then my cogroup function didn’t work well. I have tried some methods to fix my program, but they don’t work as expect. So I ask for a help to make the datastreams aligned in a cogroup operation, or any other solutions.

Comment: I suggest you increase the parallelism on the overly busy operators to the point where they can operate without back pressure. But what's going wrong, and what have you tried?

Comment: The datastreams, one is almost 100G/s and the other is about 10G/s. I should match the elements from them. I decrease the parallelism of the source operator of the "bigger" datastream. Because of the large state, I disable the checkpoint. I have also try to increase the parallelism of the cogroup operation from 300 to 480. At last, I benefit a little.

Comment: This Flink Forward talk -- https://berlin.flink-forward.org/kb_sessions/keep-it-going-how-to-reliably-and-efficiently-operate-apache-flink/ -- is a good introduction to capacity planning and performance tuning for Flink.

Comment: BTW: This is now in beta in the new 1.15 release: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment-_beta_